# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when trying to delete an entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

**I can't seem to delete a record on firebase that has been assign to a user uid, like an object inside an object.**

```
<template>
  <v-container id="tutorials">
      <h1>Gigs Available!</h1>
           <!-- loop over the tutorials -->
           <div  class="Agrid d-grid">
           <div
           class="Amodule  back"
           v-for="gig in allGigs"
           :key="gig">
           <div class="fill-height">
             <v-container >
              <a @click.prevent="deleteGigs(gig)" class="card-link">
                 <v-icon color=red>mdi-delete</v-icon>
               </a>
             <br>
             <div class="d-flex align-start">
               <h3 class="j-title center mb-00">{{ gig.gigtitle}}</h3>
             </div>
             <h6 class="">{{gig.companyname}}</h6>
             <v-row class="d-flex ">
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-clock text--secondary"> {{ gig.vacanttype }} </p>
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-earth text--secondary"> {{ gig.giglocation }} </p>
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-calendar text--secondary">{{gig.gigdate}} </p>
             </v-row>
             <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Company description</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.companydescription}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Gig description</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigdescription}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Gig benefits</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigbenefits}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Skills</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigskills}}</p><br>
           </v-container>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
     <br>

  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import nativeToast from 'native-toast'
import firebase from '@/plugins/firebase'
let db = firebase.database();
//let usersRef = db.ref('users');
let gigRef = db.ref('gigs');

export default {
  name: 'EditGigs',
  data: () => ({
  authUser: null,
  allGigs: [], // initialise an array
}),
  methods: {
       deleteGigs(gig) {
       (gigRef.child(gig.id).remove())
        console.log("Bamboozle!"+gig.id)
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    //data => console.log(data.user, data.credential.accessToken)
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          gigRef.child(user.uid).on('child_added', snapshot => {
              this.allGigs.push({...snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key
              })
              if (snapshot.val().user !== this.authUser) {
                  nativeToast({
                      message: `New message by ${snapshot.val().authUser}`,
                      type: 'success'
                  })
              }
          })
          gigRef.child(user.uid).on('child_removed', snapshot => {
              const deleteGigs = this.allGigs.find(gig => gig.id === snapshot.key)
              const index = this.allGigs.indexOf(deleteGigs)
              this.allGigs.splice(index, 1)
              if (snapshot.val().user !== this.authUser) {
                  nativeToast({
                      message: `Gig deleted by ${snapshot.val().authUser}`,
                      type: 'warning'
                  })
              }
          })
        }
     })
}
}
</script>
```

The error looks like this:

[Console log error saying TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqy4T.png)

**Here is how the data looks in firebase:**

```
Object
z0Dk4aQodPhJk7DwgJZS0kWYAaH2:
-MjxHR5FjvNgB_cvp5Q3: {companydescription: 'nudream is a startup that creates applicacionts fo…siness and upgrades current apps from businesses ', companyname: 'NuDream', gigbenefits: 'Full paid, contract imss, schema mixto alot of benefits, with alot of things ', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'we are actively looking for an ongoing poisition with strong front end skills!', …}
-MjxUCHolM-AW9pHL_gz: {companydescription: 'Canopy is developing innovative software to suppor… works, what doesn’t, and what could be improved.', companyname: 'Canopy', gigbenefits: 'Competitive salary with opportunities for performa… professional tools you need to do your best work', gigdate: '2021-09-22', gigdescription: 'Our team is growing! We’re seeking to fill several…ur software engineering and client success teams.', …}
-MjxUPZRLRhZ5xglpNAN: {companydescription: 'At GovExec, our mission is to inform and inspire g… in their work and make the world a better place.', companyname: 'Canopy', gigbenefits: 'Competitive salary with opportunities for performa… professional tools you need to do your best work', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'As the market-leading information platform, for ov…remote work can be accommodated in select states.', …}
-Mjy4Hv3G18t1lZvI2Eq: {companydescription: 'This is the company description, we will see this in a second!', companyname: 'Gigmasters', gigbenefits: 'Lots of benefits!', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'This is the Gig description!', …}
-Mjy9aKhAPNxNnWriF8K: {companydescription: 'As the market-leading information platform, for ov…s federal, defense, and state and local agencies.', companyname: 'NuStuff', gigbenefits: 'All you want!', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'As the market-leading information platform, for ov…s federal, defense, and state and local agencies.', …}
-MjzJDQBvPcPgyoLahxN: {companydescription: 'esta es mi company description ', companyname: 'Nudream', gigbenefits: 'alll you want + incentives', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'esta es mi description de gig ', …}
-Mk0OihUYZv8tQjnb7MS: {companydescription: ' adas dad aas das dasd ', companyname: 'a da da dad asd as d', gigbenefits: ' ada d sadsa dsad sad', gigdate: '2021-09-19', gigdescription: 'a da sdas das d ad sa', …}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

**This is how the data is being pushed in a separate child component form:**

```
methods: {
        addGig: function() {
            messagesRef.child(this.newGig.userID).push(this.newGig);
            this.newGig.vacanttype = '';
            this.newGig.gigtitle = '';
            this.newGig.gigdescription = '';
            this.newGig.companyname = '';
            this.newGig.companydescription = '';
            this.newGig.giglocation = '';
            this.newGig.gigdate = '';
            this.newGig.gigbenefits = '';
            this.newGig.gigskills = '';
            this.newGig.priority = '';
            toastr.success('Horray! message sent successfully');
            this.displayText = 'Nice job!';
            this.vacanttypeRules = true;
            this.gigtitleRules = true;
            this.gigdescriptionRules = true;
            this.companynameRules = true;
            this.companydescriptionRules = true;
            this.gigskillsRules = true;
            this.gigbenefitsRules = true;
            this.giglocationRules = true;
            this.priorityRules = true;
        },
```

What I am trying to do:

[Ui look for better understanding I want to delete each object on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFZuw.png)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
 <div
     // ...
     v-for="gig in allGigs":key="gig._key">
               <div ...>
                 <v-container >
                 <!-- here is my delete button -->
                   <a @click.prevent="deleteGigs(gigs)" href="#" class="card-link"><v-icon color=red>mdi-delete</v-icon></a>
```

but as indicated by the error message, `gigs` is not defined in the `v-for`.

You should do:

```
<a @click.prevent="deleteGigs(gig)"...   //gig without "s"
```

---

Or, since your `deleteGigs()` method is as follows,

```
deleteGigs(gigs) {
    gigRef.child(gigs.id).remove()
}
```

you can just pass the gig's `id`, as follows:

```
<a @click.prevent="deleteGigs(gig.id)"...>
//...

deleteGigs(gigsId) {
    gigRef.child(gigsId).remove()
}
```

Comment: Mr @RenaudTarnec I appreciate your answer, the id reference error regarding the id is out, I used the last option you mentioned, I am getting a reference error:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]""

**and a 2nd error: **
Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: You should check the value of all variable you pass to the child() method.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: If i do `  methods: {
       deleteGigs(gig) {
       (gigRef.remove())
        console.log(gig)
    }
  },`  it erases all the nodes of the ref or ( gigs ) node then if i log console.log(gig) it will trow the key I want to delete .. so i don't get it

Comment: Could it be the way I am calling the asynchronous function if so how can I improve it ?

Comment: I am getting bamboozled! I updated my whole code like 3 times and nothing I can erase the whole thing but not the key object...

Comment: A lot of people have already tried to help you. You have even created a new account and have asked four times the same question again: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16999565/whatever. without getting a solution. It is probably because the answerers do not get the correct information in order to understand your problem.